# No convergence when fitting theoretical semivariogram to empirical?

Tags: r, spatial, variogram

I'm kind of new to working with semivariograms. But I just wanted to fit a semivariogramm to my data and when fitting the theoretical variogram to my empirical it tells me that:
`Warning message: In gstat::fit.variogram(object = svgutm, model = vgm(psill = 1.2e+11,  : No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?`

So I fitted a linear model with and the summary looks like this (it's a model for housing prices):

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-835185 -116079  -25094   76765 2276897 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 407842.6    65992.5   6.180 2.67e-09 ***
area_living   2952.5      219.8  13.434  < 2e-16 ***
distance    -14266.0     2242.8  -6.361 9.83e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 286800 on 244 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4742,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4699 
F-statistic:   110 on 2 and 244 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I then calculated the semivariogram with:

```
svgutm = variogram(resids ~ 1, locations = ~utmx+utmy, data=hamburg.data)
```

and when I plot it I get this:

[image]

So I use the approcimate values for the sill, the nugget and the range to fit the theoretical one (I used a spherical) with:

```
fit.var = gstat::fit.variogram(object = svgutm, model = vgm(psill=1.2e+11, model="Sph", range=15000, nugget=4.0e+10))
```

And then I get this warning. However, I can still plot it, but it looks like this:

[image]

If anyone has any pointer to what I'm doing wrong here, I'd be super glad:)

Comment: The problem is that the empirical variogram first drops dramatically and then increases: there aren't any valid theoretical models that behave like this.  You need to do more exploratory analysis to look for (a) outliers at short distances and (b) anisotropy.

Comment: great thank you very much!!

Comment: @whuber Do you have any pointer to how I could look in R for outliers at short distances? Like just a first idea how you'd approach that which comes to your head;)

Comment: Use exploratory data analysis techniques.  The fundamental object to examine is the set of all pairs of data points $(x_0,y_0,z_0;\ x_1,y_1,z_1)$ where the $z_i$ are the observations at locations $(x_i,y_i).$ You are interested in which points show up frequently with small lags (given by $h=\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}$ and large semivariances $(z_1-z_0)^2.$ A robust way to explore these, though, is to use the fourth root of the semivariances, given by $\nu=\sqrt{|z_1-z_0|}.$  A scatterplot of $(h,\nu)$ can be a good starting point.

Comment: @whuber Thanks so much! So does it sound like a good idea to write a nested for loop that actually calculates for each pair of observations the distance h and v. However this is running wayyy too long for a dataframe with only 325 observations. I think I just cant wrap my head around the best approach here.

Comment: The usual practical limit in variography is around 300 to 1000 observations because there are already from 44,850 to 499,500 pairs to examine. Since you are interested mainly in small lags $h,$ you don't need to compute all pairs. Decent software provides efficient functions for identifying only those pairs within a specified interval of lags.  If even those functions fail -- and they often start doing so with more than a few thousand observations -- then you can divide your site into contiguous strata having smaller amounts of data and do the exploration separately within each stratum.

Comment: thank you really really much! Much appreciated